# Windows store APPX package install file in different location

Tags: windows, appx

So I have recently developed an app for the windows store, I packaged it into an APPX package. The problem is that windows auto installs it into a non-accessible folder meaning I cannot reference .exe and .pdf files.
Is there a way to make it always install 2 files in the same place, for example the two files which need to be edited install on desktop and the rest of the app in the usual install location?
Can I do this using two separate .APPX files?

Answer (score 0):

No, all APPX/MSIX packages are installed/extracted under the ProgramFiles/WindowsApps folder.

This folder is read-only, only the OS can write in there (when it's installing the app).
The solution is to copy the files you want from the install folder, the first time a user launches your application.

Comment: Thank you I will try this later!